# Microsoft MIP JAVA SDK sampe error: "Unrecognized exception: profile_add_engine_async"

Tags: azure, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

I am using MIP sdk for JAVA from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip) and trying to execute its sample to read and write MIP labels.

But when I run MIPSample for JAVA I am getting following error message in MIP log.

**"2021-02-16 12:23:38.609  common/api_utils.h:232  java (14700)    "Unrecognized exception: profile_add_engine_async"  mipns::TryExecuteFailureCallback"**

And my call to

```
Future<IFileEngine> fileEngineFuture = fileProfile.addEngineAsync(engineSettings); 
IFileEngine fileEngine = fileEngineFuture.get();
```

is not completing successfully.
In API AuthDelegateUserCredentials::acquireToken(), I am successfully able to get 'accessToken' but when I return that same access token, somewhere it crashes, before it could return and attach fileEngine instance.

I windows event viewer I m getting following error

```
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 8.0.2420.8, time stamp: 0x5e246f62
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17763.475, time stamp: 0x3230aa04
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000fb049
Faulting process id: 0x1dc0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7043c7ac79efc
Faulting application path: C:\code\depot\tools\windows\OpenJDK\1.8.0_242\x64\bin\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: ddfa73cc-d1e2-48ef-a76e-866bf67aaaa6
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Please let me know what I might be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the version of the SDK you're using? I haven't been able to reproduce this in 1.7. I'm working on a sample for 1.8 and will see if I can repro there.

Comment: Hi Tom, I am using MIP sdk version 1.8.86

Comment: I haven't been able to repro this. I should have a sample app published soon with something you can try to use to repro. I hope to have it available this evening. 

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mipsdk-filesdk-java-sample